# Tikzcd conflict with babel and cd

Tags: babel, incompatibility, tikz-cd

I have this problem: when I try to compile a diagram I get the following message:

> I think the culprit is a `tikzcd` arrow in ell 1-1

But I have not problem when, in the `tikzlibrary`, I just use `cd`, `matrix` and `backgrounds`. The problem is when using `babel` and `cd` at the same time.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath,tikz}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[mathcal]{euscript}

\usetikzlibrary{babel,cd,matrix,backgrounds}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzcd}
    X\rar[mapsto]{T}&Y
  \end{tikzcd}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. If you add code to your post, you might want to indent it by four spaces, so it gets formatted as such.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider that a bug. Please report this to the maintainers of `tikz-cd` and the `babel` library.

In the meanwhile, this hack works for you:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}

\begin{document}
    \[
    \shorthandoff{"}
        \begin{tikzcd}
            X\arrow[mapsto, "T"]{r} & Y % you have to take the old "label" syntax here 
        \end{tikzcd}
    \]  
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you do a bug report, you can use the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}

\begin{document}
        \begin{tikzcd}\null\arrow{r}{}&\null\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you add `\makeatletter` to the preamble of the MWE, it works.  I have no idea what is going on.

Comment: Actually, I know what is going on: with the babel library loaded, tikz will rescan tokens in labels (via `\scantokens`), thus changing some catcodes.

Comment: @FlorêncioNeves The `\makeatletter` is not needed in my MWE. Did you try to compile the very code I gave you? Did you report this error?