# tikz-cd doesn't compile examples from the manual

Tags: tikz-cd

I don't know if this a problem with my local TeX-Distribution (macTeX 2018) or with tikz-cd itself, how ever: I can't compile basic examples from the tikz-cd manual, like this:

```
    \documentclass{standalone}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
    \usepackage{xcolor}

    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{lmodern}

    \usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}


    \usepackage{tikz-cd}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{tikzcd}
        A \arrow[r, "\phi"] \arrow[d, red]
                & B \arrow[d, "\psi" red] \\
        C \arrow[r, red, "\eta" blue]
            &D \end{tikzcd}

    \end{document}
```

The resulting output is
[image: Compiled document]

And the errors messages inside the log start with this error message:

```
    ! Argument of \language@active@arg" has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.18        &D \end{tikzcd}

I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.

Runaway argument?
! Paragraph ended before \language@active@arg" was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.18        &D \end{tikzcd}
```

Any ideas what the problem might be? The macTeX-Distribution is complete and up-to-date as of april 4th 2019.

Comment: I can connfirm the error messages that you get. However, the MWE compiles just fine, if you remove `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}`.

Comment: This is crazy, removing babel from the preamble "solves" the problem for me, too. Yet, this is no solution, as babel is essential for good typesetting. :<

Comment: The following question is a possible duplicate: [Tikzcd conflict with babel and cd](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/203843/134144) and the proposed workaround also works for your case.

Comment: Just a note: If you use `LuaTeX` or `XeTeX`, then you might be able to substitute `babel` with https://ctan.org/pkg/polyglossia.

Comment: @leandriis Thank you for the help, great!

Comment: @CampanIgnis No, thanks, I do not wish to use LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve the your question you can add `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` always confirming that you can use `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}`. Now there is no errors.

[image]

```
    \documentclass{standalone}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
    \usepackage{tikz-cd}
    \usetikzlibrary{babel}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzcd}
        A \arrow[r, "\phi"] \arrow[d, red]
                & B \arrow[d, "\psi" red] \\
        C \arrow[r, red, "\eta" blue]
            &D 
    \end{tikzcd}
    \end{document}
```